# Color coding Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

Can I somehow color code my inbox in terms of importance?

For example, the email for ASAP shows as red in my inbox, yellow as SOON, and green as IN THE WEEK?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for [**labels**](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067566?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). You can organize your emails by setting up labels. Labels work like folders, but you can add more than one label to a message.

[Organize your Gmail inbox using labels](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/118708?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

**Create a label**

> 1. On your computer, open Inbox.
> 2. On the left, click **Create new**.
> 3. Type a name for your label and click **Save**.
> 4. Click **Close**.

**Add a label to a message you received**

> 1. Open Gmail.
> 2. Open a message.
> 3. At the top, click Label icon.
> 4. Click the box next to each label you want to add, or type a new label.